# Account management

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm completely new to WCF, so I'm sorry if this question sounds dumb..

I'd like to create a web service which will have account management. What I mean is that I have a client which can request the service to register a new account, login and link things to my account.

The accounts are stored in a SQL Server database.

I have this interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Register(string username,  string password);
}
```

In the class that implements the service, the new account is entered into the database.

Is this the right way of doing this or should I do this another way? Also, what about security? Obviously the password will be hashed in the database (I'm creating the hash in the method), but sending it to the service in clear text doesn't seem like the correct way.

The second problem is that I'd like to use a custom UserNamePasswordValidator so the client can only call the methods after authenticating (see my previous question: [Basic authentication and WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430645/basic-authentication-and-wcf/15431009#comment21829281_15431009))

The problem is that I'd like to create an exception: you have to log in for every method EXCEPT the register method. Is there a way to do this? Or should I create a seperate service just for this one method?

I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In WCF you sould use Transport or Message security to secure your messages. Implementing this is enought for you to secure your sending password. The Transport security will provide you SSL/TSL, while the message security will secure your messages according to WS-Security specification. If you want you can use both of them. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137.aspx about advantages and disadvantages of message security and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729700.aspx about transport.
2. Before enabling your custom validation you **MUST** implement one of above security models. When you implement your custom validation, it is just another security check before opening your channel. For example you have a code with custom security

   ```
    factory = new ChannelFactory<IContract>(binding,
                   new EndpointAddress(address, EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity(serviceCertificate)));
    factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerOrChainTrust;
    factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "admin";
    factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "qwerty";
    channel = factory.CreateChannel();
   ```

When you create such channel, there first will be certificate check, then in your service side it will call Validate() method. There you can check your login and pass and throw exception, if they are wrong. So factory.CreateChannel() will return you exception, and the channel will not be built, so you would not be able to call any of your service methods. If you want to use only one method, I would recommend you to use stand-alone service for registaration purposes only or you can try to put your registration logic into your Validate() method.

Comment: Thanks, but where do I have to put my Register-method as you don't need to login for that? Will I have to create a seperate service just for that method?

Comment: @Bv202 I advice you to create a separate service with one Register method, which would work without validation, only with transport security, and another service with your custom validation. It would be the right approach.

Comment: Okay, thanks. What if my client can't handle certificates? My client is a Windows Phone application..

Comment: @Bv202 Oh, then you sould use transport security. You service won't work without it.  It can't pass your credentials without secure channal (except BasicHttpBinding, which is strongly not recommended)