# Custom security module after windows authentication

Tags: c#, wcf

I'd like to create a custom security module which will run on all services once authentication occurs.

All services would be configured to support Windows authentication. If authentication is successful the custom security module would be responsible for: verifying <strike>validating</strike> the user against a database and creating a custom principal and setting it to a property of the WCF operation context.

Would I need to implement this using a custom ServiceBehaviour, EndpointBehaviour or are there other alternatives?

To which property should I set my custom principal?

Could somebody nudge me in the right direction?

Thanks

**Update 1**
I used the word "Validate" above, my error I should of used "Verify" as the module would only verify that the user exists. To verify that the user exists the module wouldn't need to receive the user's password. I'd like to continue using "Windows" as the clientCredentialType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom validation for this. It will allow you to add additional security check of some data by your custom logic. You have to make validation class, inherited from  UserNamePasswordValidator and override Validate() method, where you can pass some data and use your logic to handle with it. There is a good example on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2007/10/05/wcf-authentication-custom-username-and-password-validator.aspx

Yesterday I had a discussion on this topic with Bvb202. If it is interesting to you read [Account management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471873/account-management/15472306#15472306)

Comment: Thanks voo. I've updated my question. It seems that the custom UserNamePasswordValidator is mostly appropiate when using "UserName" as the ClientCredentialType? As I don't need the user's password I'd like to continue using windows as the credentialType. Any suggestions? Should I continue using the UserNamePasswordValidator?

Comment: @rauland You want to change you service thread principal if your user is in some DB group?

Comment: I'd like to set the principal in the "custom security module" so I can later  reference it from inside the service methods. I'll won't be taking into account roles or groups.

Comment: @rauland Well, I see no problems in this then. There is a good link about it in http://leastprivilege.com/2007/08/08/custom-principals-and-wcf/ You should implement is without UserNamePasswordValidator